# Google Play services library missing

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build.gradle, google-play-services

I have been trying to use google play services library but I just cannot find the latest version of the library. It gives me an error when I use the wrong version and also error when I remove it.

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services: **X.X.X** ' is what i want to use

Can anyone tell me what number do I put in place of X.X.X?? Google website has versions for all other libraries like auth, base, identity except that for google play-services

Thank you

Comment: use only what u required . https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I need maps and location, so I have used that library, but the moment I remove implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services' it throws a lot of errors :(

Comment: Follow the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) and samples  u probably missing some configuration.